# How can you solve "Could not find a part of the path" error?

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2012

I want to save images in a server, I'm using VS C# 2012 and for the server I'm using IIS with my IP, but every time I put the image, I get the error:

> Could not find a part of the path 187.184.43.27\CyF.jpg

Don't know if the error is in the path sintax or in something else.

this is my code to save the image.

```
private void cmd_imagen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Archivos jpg(*.jpg)|*.jpg";
    open.Title = "Archivos jpg";
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string dir = open.FileName;
        string destino = Path.Combine("187.184.43.27", Path.GetFileName(dir));
        File.Copy(dir, destino);//This is the line where i get the error
    }
    open.Dispose();
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `187.184.43.27` looks like an IP and not a folder so, shouldn't it be `\\187.184.43.27` if that is a local server in your network? And that is assuming you have rights to access that server and store data there.

Comment: inetpub is shared public and everyone has access i put the path as you suggest and im still getting the same error

Comment: and if you type it on explorer does it work? if it doesn't work on explorer means that is not a shareable folder but rather an accessible URL which is 2 different things. Accessing `http://187.184.43.27/CyF.jpg` is not the same of `\\187.184.43.27\CyF.jpg`

Comment: yes, i think you can enter too, i use this for some time for school proyects that required to make our pc our own server

Comment: Don't `think` check it and make sure it works otherwise the application will not work as well... 1) Make sure the folder is accessible from the computer you're trying to remotely accessing it via your network 2) Make sure you have write-able access to it

Comment: ok i check and change the path to \\gordo-pc\\wwwroot (my network path) and i get the DirectoryNotFoundException.

Comment: `@"\\gordo-pc\wwwroot"` and does your computer knows that gordo-pc is the server? if it doesn't or the server folder is not there it won't work either.

Comment: that's it, it work i can save now files.
thanks for the help